# Turning a Dataframe with lists into columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

```py
#takes group object applys a group by civil twilight groupby then takes the avearge of several columns
funct_day_night = lambda x: [x['Severity'].mean(), x["Distance(mi)"].mean(), x['Severity'].count()]
group_group_df = group_df.apply(lambda g_df : g_df.groupby('Civil_Twilight').apply(funct_day_night))
group_group_df
```

[image]

I want to turn all of the output on the right into columns. Please link me to the documentation I was not sure what to even look up. It might be best to answer the question in two parts one with fixing the function above and the other with fixing the out put either solution will work for me.

The data set I used was: https://www.kaggle.com/sobhanmoosavi/us-accidents

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas split column of lists into multiple columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35491274/pandas-split-column-of-lists-into-multiple-columns)

Comment: My data comes out as a  pandas series when I print it it shows it like that for some reason

Comment: I don't think that method will work

Comment: [explode?](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html)

Comment: @JuanRamos What do you mean by _My data comes out as a pandas series when I print it it shows it like that for some reason_? If you can share a proper [mcve], we should be able to find an all around better way of doing this.

Comment: I was able to figure it out using `pivot_table` I used the parameter `aggfunc = [np.mean, Count]` . So I avoided using `groupby`